# Java - Creating Dynamic Vertex + Edges (Dijkstra Algorithm)

Tags: java, dijkstra, vertex, edges

I'm trying to generate Vertex + edges dynamically, but I'm getting errors when I try to compute the shortest path between coordinates.

TestDijkstra3.java:

```
package maze_drawing;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>
{
 public final String name;
 public static String faceDirection;
 public Edge[] adjacencies;
 public double minDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
 public Vertex previous;
 public Vertex(String argName) {
    name = argName;
}
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
public int compareTo(Vertex other)
{
    return Double.compare(minDistance, other.minDistance);
}
}
class Edge
 {
public final Vertex target;
public final String direction;
public Edge(Vertex argTarget, String argDirection){
    target = argTarget;
    direction = argDirection;
   }
 }

public class TestDijkstra3
{
public static void computePaths(Vertex source, String faceDirection)
{

    source.minDistance = 0;
    double turningweight = 0;
    String robotDirection = faceDirection;
    PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexQueue = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>();
vertexQueue.add(source);

while (!vertexQueue.isEmpty()) {
    Vertex u = vertexQueue.poll();

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : u.adjacencies)
        {
            Vertex v = e.target;
            //double weight = e.weight;
            String direction = e.direction; //DIRECTION TO DESTINATION


            double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + 10 + turningweight;
    if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
        vertexQueue.remove(v);

        v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
        v.previous = u;

                robotDirection = direction;

        vertexQueue.add(v);
    }
        }
    }
}

public static List<Vertex> getShortestPathTo(Vertex target)
{
    List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    for (Vertex vertex = target; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
        path.add(vertex);

    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    int startX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endX = 3;
    int endY = 3;
    String facing = "N";
    String start = ""+startX+""+startY;
    String end = ""+endX+""+endY;

    Vertex v00 = new Vertex("00");
Vertex v10 = new Vertex("10");
Vertex v20 = new Vertex("20");
Vertex v30 = new Vertex("30");
    Vertex v40 = new Vertex("40");
    Vertex v50 = new Vertex("50");
    Vertex v60 = new Vertex("60");
Vertex v01 = new Vertex("01");
Vertex v11 = new Vertex("11");
Vertex v21 = new Vertex("21");
    Vertex v31 = new Vertex("31");
    Vertex v41 = new Vertex("41");
    Vertex v51 = new Vertex("51");
    Vertex v61 = new Vertex("61");
Vertex v02 = new Vertex("02");
Vertex v12 = new Vertex("12");
Vertex v22 = new Vertex("22");
Vertex v32 = new Vertex("32");
    Vertex v42 = new Vertex("42");
    Vertex v52 = new Vertex("52");
    Vertex v62 = new Vertex("62");
Vertex v03 = new Vertex("03");
Vertex v13 = new Vertex("13");
    Vertex v23 = new Vertex("23");
Vertex v33 = new Vertex("33");
    Vertex v43 = new Vertex("43");
    Vertex v53 = new Vertex("53");
    Vertex v63 = new Vertex("63");
    Vertex v04 = new Vertex("04");
Vertex v14 = new Vertex("14");
Vertex v24 = new Vertex("24");
Vertex v34 = new Vertex("34");
    Vertex v44 = new Vertex("44");
    Vertex v54 = new Vertex("54");
    Vertex v64 = new Vertex("64");
    Vertex v05 = new Vertex("05");
Vertex v15 = new Vertex("15");
Vertex v25 = new Vertex("25");
Vertex v35 = new Vertex("35");
    Vertex v45 = new Vertex("45");
    Vertex v55 = new Vertex("55");
    Vertex v65 = new Vertex("65");
    Vertex v06 = new Vertex("06");
Vertex v16 = new Vertex("16");
Vertex v26 = new Vertex("26");
Vertex v36 = new Vertex("36");
    Vertex v46 = new Vertex("46");
    Vertex v56 = new Vertex("56");
    Vertex v66 = new Vertex("66");

v00.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v10,  "E"), new Edge(v01,  "N") };
v10.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v00,  "S"), new Edge(v20,  "E") };
v20.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v10,  "W"), new Edge(v21,  "N"), new Edge(v30,  "E") };
    v30.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v20,  "W"), new Edge(v31,  "N"), new Edge(v40,  "E") };
    v40.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v30,  "W"), new Edge(v50,  "E") };
    v50.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v40,  "W"), new Edge(v51,  "N") };
    v60.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v61,  "N") };
    v01.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v02,  "N"), new Edge(v00,  "S") };
    v11.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v12,  "N") };
    v21.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v31,  "E"), new Edge(v20,  "S") };
    v31.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v21,  "W"), new Edge(v30,  "S") };
    v41.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v51,  "E"), new Edge(v42,  "N") };
    v51.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v50,  "S"), new Edge(v41,  "W") };
    v61.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v60,  "S"), new Edge(v62,  "N") };
    v02.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v01,  "S"), new Edge(v03,  "N") };
    v12.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v11,  "S"), new Edge(v13,  "N"), new Edge(v22,  "E") };
    v22.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v12,  "W"), new Edge(v32,  "E") };
    v32.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v22,  "W"), new Edge(v42,  "E") };
    v42.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v32,  "W"), new Edge(v41,  "S"), new Edge(v43,  "N") };
    v52.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v62,  "E") };
    v62.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v52,  "W"), new Edge(v61,  "S"), new Edge(v63,  "N") };
    v03.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v13,  "E"), new Edge(v02,  "S"), new Edge(v04,  "N") };
    v13.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v03,  "W"), new Edge(v23,  "E"), new Edge(v12,  "S") };
v23.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v13,  "W"), new Edge(v33,  "E") };
    v33.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v34,  "N"), new Edge(v23,  "W") };
    v43.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v42,  "S"), new Edge(v44,  "N"), new Edge(v53,  "E") };
    v53.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v43,  "W") };
    v63.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v62,  "S"), new Edge(v64,  "N") };
    v04.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v05,  "N"), new Edge(v03,  "S") };
    v14.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v15,  "N"), new Edge(v24,  "E") };
v24.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v14,  "W"), new Edge(v25,  "N") };
    v34.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v33,  "S"), new Edge(v35,  "N") };
    v44.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v45,  "N"), new Edge(v43,  "S") };
    v54.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v64,  "E") };
    v64.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v54,  "W"), new Edge(v65,  "N"), new Edge(v63,  "S") };
    v05.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v06,  "N"), new Edge(v04,  "S") };
    v15.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v14,  "S") };
v25.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v26,  "N"), new Edge(v24,  "S") };
    v35.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v36,  "N"), new Edge(v34,  "S") };
    v45.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v55,  "E"), new Edge(v44,  "S") };
    v55.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v45,  "W") };
    v65.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v64,  "S"), new Edge(v66,  "N") };
    v06.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v16,  "E"), new Edge(v05,  "S") };
    v16.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v06,  "W"), new Edge(v26,  "E") };
v26.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v16,  "W"), new Edge(v25,  "S") };
    v36.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v35,  "S"), new Edge(v46,  "E") };
    v46.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v36,  "W"), new Edge(v56,  "E") };
    v56.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v46,  "W"), new Edge(v66,  "E") };
    v66.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v56,  "W"), new Edge(v65,  "S") };

Vertex[] vertices = { v00, v10, v20, v30, v40, v50, v60, v01, v11, v21, v31, v41, v51, v61, v02, v12, v22, v32, v42, v52, v62, v03, v13, v23, v33, v43, v53, v63, v04, v14, v24, v34, v44, v54, v64, v05, v15, v25, v35, v45, v55, v65, v06, v16, v26, v36, v46, v56, v66 };

    Vertex[] vertices2 = new Vertex[49];

    System.out.println("Start");

    HentMazeFil mazeFile = new HentMazeFil();
    String lineCoords;

    Vertex v[] = new Vertex[67];
    String Rest[] = new String[67];
    String wholeLine[] = new String[49];

    for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
        lineCoords = mazeFile.nextLineCoords();

        if (lineCoords != null) {
            v[Integer.parseInt(lineCoords.substring(0, 2))] = new Vertex(lineCoords.substring(0, 2));
            Rest[Integer.parseInt(lineCoords.substring(0, 2))] = new String(lineCoords.substring(2, 6));
            wholeLine[i] = lineCoords;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Line = Null"); // End of while loop.

            break;
        }
        lineCoords = mazeFile.nextLineCoords(); // Skipping "extra lines" from Linux files.
    }

    //System.out.println(vertices);
    //System.out.println(vertices2);

    String line;
    //Adding edges
    for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
        line = wholeLine[i];
        v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))] = new Vertex(line.substring(0, 2));
        Rest[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))] = new String(line.substring(2, 6));

            if (line.charAt(2) == '0') {
                if (line.charAt(3) == '0') {
                    if (line.charAt(4) == '0') {
                        if (line.charAt(5) == '0') {
                            v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+1], "N") ,new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+10], "E"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-1], "S"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-10], "W")};
                        }
                        else {
                            v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+1], "N") ,new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+10], "E"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-1], "S")};
                        }
                    }
                    else if (line.charAt(5) == '0') {
                            v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+1], "N") ,new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+10], "E"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-10], "W")};
                        }
                    else {
                        v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+1], "N") ,new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+10], "E")};

                    }
                }
                else if (line.charAt(4) == '0') {
                        if (line.charAt(5) == '0') {
                            v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+1], "N"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-1], "S"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-10], "W")};
                        }
                        else {
                            v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+1], "N") , new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-1], "S")};
                        }
                }
                else if (line.charAt(5) == '0') {
                    v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+1], "N") , new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-10], "W")};
                }
                else {
                    v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+1], "N")};
                }

            }
            else if (line.charAt(3) == '0') {
                    if (line.charAt(4) == '0') {
                        if (line.charAt(5) == '0') {
                            v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+10], "E"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-1], "S"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-10], "W")};
                        }
                        else {
                            v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+10], "E"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-1], "S")};
                        }
                    }
                    else if (line.charAt(5) == '0') {
                        v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+10], "E"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-10], "W")};
                    }
                    else {
                        v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))+10], "E")};
                    }

            }
            else if(line.charAt(4) == '0') {
                        if (line.charAt(5) == '0') {
                            v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-1], "S"), new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-10], "W")};
                        }
                        else {
                            v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))].adjacencies = new Edge[] {new Edge (v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))-1], "S")};
                        }
                    }

    }//end of i loop

    int z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 67; i++) {
        if (v[i] != null) {
            vertices2[z] = v[i];
            //System.out.println(vertices2[z]);
            z++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("v[0] = "+v[0]);
    for (Edge e :v[0].adjacencies) {
        System.out.println("Target: "+e.target);
    }
    System.out.println("v[1] = "+v[1]);
    for (Edge e :v[1].adjacencies) {
        System.out.println("Target: "+e.target);
    }

    System.out.println("End");

    for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
        if (vertices[i].toString().equals(start)) {
            computePaths(vertices[i], facing);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
        if (vertices[i].toString().equals(end)) {
            System.out.println("Distance to " + vertices[i] + ": " + vertices[i].minDistance);
            List<Vertex> path = getShortestPathTo(vertices[i]);
            System.out.println("Path: " + path);

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("traversalfile.txt", "UTF-8");

            for (int j = 0; j < path.size()-1; j++) {
                int directionValue = Integer.parseInt(path.get(j+1).toString())-Integer.parseInt(path.get(j).toString());
                if (directionValue == 1) {
                    System.out.println("N");
                    writer.println("N");
                }
                else if (directionValue == 10) {
                    System.out.println("E");
                    writer.println("E");
                }
                else if (directionValue == -1) {
                    System.out.println("S");
                    writer.println("S");
                }
                else if (directionValue == -10) {
                    System.out.println("W");
                    writer.println("W");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
                }
            }
            writer.close();

        }

    }

}
}
```

As you see, there's 2 options along the code: A solution, with hardcoded vertex + edges (first part), which is working fine, and a more dynamic approach, which read the from a .txt file, and from that it should convert these readings into vertex + edges.
My error is, when I change "vertices" --> "vertices2", in the end of the code, so I should use the dynamic Vertex method, I get and error: 
"Start
v[0] = 00
Target: 01
Target: 10
v[1] = 01
Target: 02
Target: 00
End
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at maze_drawing.TestDijkstra3.computePaths(TestDijkstra3.java:60)
at maze_drawing.TestDijkstra3.main(TestDijkstra3.java:341) //This is at "computePaths(vertices2[i], facing);"
Java Result: 1"

However, if I just run it with "vertices" (as in the code above), the result is just fine:

Start
v[0] = 00
Target: 01
Target: 10
v[1] = 01
Target: 02
Target: 00
End
Distance to 33: 60.0
Path: [00, 01, 02, 03, 13, 23, 33]
N
N
N
E
E
E

For some reason, there must be some kind of difference, between "vertices" & "vertices2". If I print them in a for loop, I get:

output:
V1: 00
V2: 00
V1: 10
V2: 01
V1: 20
V2: 02
V1: 30
V2: 03
V1: 40
V2: 04
... etc

It goes wrong here:

```
int z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 67; i++) {
        if (v[i] != null) {
            vertices2[z] = v[i];
            System.out.println(vertices2[z]);
            z++;
        }

    }
```

So I have 2 problems:
1. I can't seem to figure out how to change the above for loop, so it read @10 first (See "newtestmap.map" for how it should look), and then @1.
2. I still think that "computepath" should work, even though the arrays order is kinda messed in vertices2, but it doesn't.

Can you see where the problem is ?

Thanks in advance.

HentMazeFil.java :

```
package maze_drawing;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HentMazeFil {

java.io.File file;
String lineCoords;
Scanner input;

public HentMazeFil() {
    file = new java.io.File("newtestmap.map");
    try {
        input = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File dont exist");
    }
}

public String nextLineCoords() {
    if (input.hasNext()) {
        lineCoords = input.nextLine();

        return lineCoords;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

newtestmap.map:

```
000011

101010

200010

300010

401010

500110

600111

010101

110111

211001

311100

410011

511100

610101

020101

120001

221010

321010

420100

521011

620100

030001

131000

231010

330110

430001

531110

630101

040101

140011

240110

340101

440101

541011

640100

050101

151101

250101

350101

451001

551110

650101

061001

161010

261100

361001

461010

561010

661100
```

Comment: I managed to find a solution, for the first problem - How to enter v[] into vertices2[] correctly. I simply moved it up, 2 lines under:
line = wholeLine[i];
No for loops or anything, simply just vertices2[i] = v[Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 2))];
I'm still having trouble with the other part though.